# Linear Programming with constraints of the form $Cx \nless d$ where $C\in R^{m\times n}$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem that has a linear objective function. The constraints are of the form: $(Ax \leq b) \wedge (Cx \nless d)$. 
In other words, I have:

\begin{align}
\min &f^T x 
\notag \\
\text{s.t.}
&Ax \leq b \\
&Cx \nless d\\
\end{align}

One way to solve the problem would be to decompose the constraint $Cx \nless d$ into $m$ constraints (assuming $C\in R^{m\times n}$): 
\begin{align}
     & c_1^T x &\geq &d_1 \\
\vee & c_2^T x &\geq &d_2 \\
     &         & \vdots & \\
\vee & c_m^T x &\geq &d_m \\
\end{align}
and we end up solving $m$ linear programs that are exactly the same except for one constraint that changes from one LP to another. Global optimum is simply the best among the $m$ optimums obtained.

Can anyone think of a faster way to perform this optimization? What about convex relaxation? How would I relax my problem to a single linear program? How good a convex relaxation solution would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constraint $Cx \nless d$ is can be expressed as a mixed-integer program under certain conditions.

\begin{eqnarray}
C_i x - M_i y_i    &\ge& d_i \hspace{0.3 in} \forall i \in I \\
\sum_{i \in I} y_i &\le& m-1 \\
y_i   &\in& \{ 0, 1 \} \hspace{0.2 in} \forall i \in I 
\end{eqnarray}

Where $I = \{1, \ldots m\}$, $M_i$ is a constant that represents an a-priori upper-bound on $c_i x$.  If A good mixed-integer solver should do better than solving the $m$ separate continuous problems.

Comment: Thank you. I am using MOSEK and I hope I can get fast results because $m$ can be very high and I have to repeat the process several times. What do you think convex relaxation would do in this case? If we allow $y_i$ to be real, we obviously get a lower bound. From what I see, the relaxed space boils down to simply $Ax \leq b$. Is that right?

Comment: @Fawaz Depending on the problem, you might be able to or need to do better than just $Ax \le b$.  The smaller you can make the $M_i$, the better.  It is ok to eliminate a-priori suboptimal solutions.